# Set percentage value with constraint layout

Tags: android

Here I have 2 guidelines in order to have a view scaled in relation to the screen size. But how set the view in order to the constraints depends on the size of the screen ?

[image: Here the current constraint of my view (absolute values...)]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give an id to the guidelines, and set the constraints Start -> StartOf @id/guidelines1
hope i've answered your question.

Comment: Thank you. It works. Another question. Is possible to set the offset (margin) in percentage ?

Comment: yes you can set a margin of a view in percentage but you can't set offset of a guideline